# Temporary objects in parallel computing in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a pretty long R code which needs to be iterated several hundred times. I am using a 32 core and 32 GB RAM cloud service to do the job. To make the code run faster, I want to use parallel computing using foreach() command. I have set the codes working with no errors. However, I need to make sure if I am getting proper results. To illustrate my point I have set a simplified mock code:

```
foreach (i = 1:100) %dopar% {
age <- seq(from=20,to=79, by=1)
d <- as.data.frame(age)
d$gender <- rbinom(nrow(d),size = 1,prob = 0.5)
d$prob <- cut(d$age, breaks = c(20,30,40,50,60,70,80), include.lowest = T,right = F,labels = c(.001,.01,.1,.25,.3,.1))
d$prob <- as.numeric(as.character(d$prob))
d$event <- rbinom(nrow(d),size = 1,prob = d$prob)
save(d,file = paste("d_",i,".rda", sep = ""))
table(d$gender,d$event)
}
```

I am wondering if temporary objects, like “d” in this example, is independent for each cluster when running this code. If there is only one object “d” in the memory which is shared by different clusters, what is the solution for an independent object.
For reference, I am using the code proposed by this page (https://github.com/tobigithub/R-parallel) to make clusters.
Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: There is no shared memory in parallelized foreach loops. The loop body must be completely independent between iterations or you can't parallelize it. So, yes, your temporary objects are independent.

Comment: Yes, `y <- foreach(i = 1:100) %dopar% { ... }` is no different in this sense than, say, `y <- lapply(i = 1:100, FUN = function(i) { ... })`.  Despite the similarity in names, `foreach()` is _not_ a `for (i in 1:100) { ... }` loop.